# Node-red Java web application

Tags: java, workflow, node-red

I am developing a web application. I need workflows to be dynamically created, customized and then executed. I have gone through Node-red.

1. Is it possible to integrate node-red as a part of my application?
2. If Yes, how to load Node-red with my defined nodes within my application?
3. What is the execution engine used in node-red?

Is there any proper documentation for the integration/embedding of node-red with other web application

Comment: Given your questions you do not seam to have actually done any research on Node-RED yourself, answers to all those questions can be found on the Node-RED website.

Comment: @hardillb Thanks for your comment. I have gone through the Node-RED website. 
1. I want to integrate Node-RED framework(without any nodes) inside my application. I will add my own customized nodes. 
2. Single node execution - Is it possible to select any single node in a workflow and to independently execute that node alone?

Comment: Those are totally separate questions from the ones you originally asked

Answer (score 1):

A few points:

- Node-RED is written in Javascript running on NodeJS, not Java (this is mentioned on the front page of the Node-RED website)
- Documentation on how to embed Node-RED into another NodeJS application can be found [here](https://nodered.org/docs/embedding)
- Documentation on how to write your own nodes is found [here](https://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/)